# Power charge shot while holding mousebuttondown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which fires a linerenderer from a start to end position with each click. I want to have a linerender that is constant until the mouse button is released. Like a power charge. What do I need to add in the script to make this happen?

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RayCastShot : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float fireRate = 0.25f;
public float weaponRange = 50f;
public float hitForce = 100f;
public Transform gunEndLeft;
public Transform gunEndRight;


private Camera fpsCam;
private WaitForSeconds shotDuration = new WaitForSeconds(0.07f);
private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private float nextFire;

public Material mat1;
public Material mat2;




void Start()
{
    lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    fpsCam = GetComponent<Camera>();


}


void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire)
    {
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

        StartCoroutine(ShotEffect());

        Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

        RaycastHit hit;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, gunEndLeft.position);

        lineRenderer.material = mat1;




        if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange))
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hit.point);

            //get reference to hit point
        }

        if(hit.rigidbody !=null)
        {
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * hitForce);
        }

        else
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, rayOrigin + (fpsCam.transform.forward * weaponRange));
        }
    }




    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2") && Time.time > nextFire)
    {
        nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;

        StartCoroutine(ShotEffect());

        Vector3 rayOrigin = fpsCam.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

        RaycastHit hit;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, gunEndRight.position);

        lineRenderer.material = mat2;

        //lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Priority Additive"));







        if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, weaponRange))
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hit.point);

            //get reference to hit point
        }

        if (hit.rigidbody != null)
        {
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * hitForce);
        }

        else
        {
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, rayOrigin + (fpsCam.transform.forward * weaponRange));
        }
    }




}

private IEnumerator ShotEffect()
{
    lineRenderer.enabled = true;

    yield return shotDuration;

    lineRenderer.enabled = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start by use `Input.GetButtonUp` to stop the fire.
That way you can start on `Input.GetButtonDown` and stop only when buttonUp.
If you need to execute code every frame you can also use `Input.GetButton`.

That's the basic idea.